# How to verify 2 statements in a "if" condition in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a request from a client :
I have a disclamer, if I want to access a content I must check a checkbox and click on a button.

```
<div class="accept">
    <label>I accept the licence agreement</label>
    <input type="checkbox" />
</div>

<div class="next">
        <button>Next</button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="download-content">some content</div>
```

`div.download-content` is `display:none` when the 2 conditions is verified show `div.download-content`

Thank you or your help!

Comment: the best way would be to write an if statement in JQuery I guess...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something as simple as the following? It's a little hard to understand exactly what you mean, as it's not 2 conditions but rather 1 condition and one event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.next button').click(function() {
        if ($('.accept input:checkbox').is(':checked')) {
            $('.download-content').show();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: In deed, you're correct. And your code works perfectly. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can bind a [click handler](http://api.jquery.com/click/) on the Next button that will check if the checkbox is [checked](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/), and if so, just [show](http://api.jquery.com/show/) the content.